# Is it "as many electrons" or "as much electrons"?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I thought it would be "as many electrons", because electrons is a countable noun, but Google shows that ["as much electrons"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20much%20electrons%22) is more popular than ["as many electrons"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20many%20electrons%22)

Comment: It would be a challenge to count those electrons, won't it?

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+electrons%2C+as+many+electrons&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20many%20electrons%3B%2Cc0) doesn't even find "as much electrons".  And a lot of your hits for "as much" appear to be from Oriental authors, suggesting that "as much" is the idiom there.  "As many electrons" is the correct term in the US (and probably the UK).

Comment: @Lior: If I have my Heisenberg right, one could google or count them but not both ;-)

Comment: Dorgan: That Google shows "as much electrons" to be more common than "as many electrons" utterly astounds me, and not in a good way.

Comment: If you actually count the number of results for each it's 53 and 172 respectively (although I didn't bother to filter duplicate results in either of these totals). In other words (as I've said many timed before) when Google says "about *N* results", it's a very very poor estimate.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. *Electron* is a countable noun, and once it's pluralised to *electrons* it needs *many*.

Mass/uncountable nouns are always singular: as much *furniture* as possible; or *charge* or *space* or *current* or *gravy.*

The only countable noun I can think of which **might** take *much* is "mushy peas". But again, mushy peas come as an amorphous blob of green stuff. It's literally a mass noun.

Comment: Vestiges of "pease"?

Answer (score 0):

It would be as many electrons.
If google shows as much electrons, it would be the most popular form.
Just because it is the most popular form, doesn't mean it's correct.
Scince an atom's number of electrons is countable, many is needed.
If it was as much as you can fit somewhere, it wouldn't be countable so you would say as much.
I hope this was of use to you.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be 'as many as you can fit in there'? It's still countable right? Even if the number is infinite you could say 'you can fit infinitely many electrons in there', right?

Comment: No. Because an atom can only hold a certain amount of electrons.

Comment: Nobody said anything about atoms. What about the number of electrons that could fit in a litre? Is that bound above? suppose the litre is full of atoms with the maximum density of electrons, could you still add an electron? Maybe some gamma radiation?

Comment: It's because the only place you would describe electrons are in atoms or in colliders where you have singular electrons.

Comment: What about electrons in space? The number of electrons per unit of volume might be important for protecting satellites (probably along with other parameters). See [this article by NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/nasa-mission-uncovers-dance-of-electrons-in-space).

Comment: You measure FEV (full electron volume) but only in relation to atoms and their ionic compounds. You don't find lone electrons wandering around- they're always in an orbital shell on an atom unless they have been extracted manually using semi-nuclear magnetising. Taking this into account, you'd just use Avagadro's number to find the amount of atoms with the RAM (relative atomic mass) and use the electron count to do the rest. That is much easier than finding the volume as a percentage and the taking it away from the entire weight of the volume, for this you'd need a very strong nuclear force.

Comment: Okay, we're getting rather technical now. My point was (and still is) that you'd say 'infinitely many', because it is countable. The expression 'infinitely much' doesn't make sense. Also, _number of atoms_, not _amount_, because atoms are also countable. ;)